# How to solve an equation with two variables in Mathematica

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

If I solved an example equation like `|x|+|y|=1` numerically, I would to get a 90° rotated rectangle. If I was to plot the equation, it would result in an image like the following:

[image: example problem]

As an example, this is the problem I want to solve:

```
Sin[x] Sin[2y] + Sin[y] Sin[2x] = 0
```

May I get suggestions on the best method to plot the example problem achieving the same result?

Comment: I suppose you looked in the documentation for `Solve`? What problem did you encounter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ContourPlot[Abs[x] + Abs[y] == 1, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]
```

[image]

```
ContourPlot[Sin[x] Sin[2 y] + Sin[y] Sin[2 x] == 0, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image]

You can change the limits of the ContourPlot if there's a particular region or feature you want to illustrate.